# Service is returning null despite running in the background

Tags: java, android, service

I am trying to implement an Instant Messaging functionality into my app following this guide: https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/#start the sinch client

I have followed everything in the guide exactly, but when I attempt to send a message I get a NullPointerException. Here is the guilty code:

```
private void sendMessage() {
    messageBody = messageBodyField.getText().toString();
    if (messageBody.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "messageService: " + messageService);
    Log.i(TAG, "recipientId: " + recipientId);
    Log.i(TAG, "messageBody: " + messageBody);
    messageService.sendMessage(recipientId, messageBody);
    messageBodyField.setText("");
}
```

From the logs, I see that the recipientId and messageBody are properly assigned, and that the messageService object is null. Below is the full code of the activity:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "ChatActivity";
private String recipientId;
private EditText messageBodyField;
private ListView messagesList;
private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
private String messageBody;
private MessageService.MessageServiceInterface messageService;
private String currentUserId;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
private MessageClientListener messageClientListener = new MyMessageClientListener();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);

    bindService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    //Log.i("Tag", "bindService(): " + bindService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

    messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_chat);
    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this);
    messagesList.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

    loadMessageHistory();

    messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_messageBodyField);

    findViewById(R.id.button_send).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void loadMessageHistory() {
    String[] userIds = {currentUserId, recipientId};
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
    query.whereContainedIn("senderId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
    query.whereContainedIn("recipientId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < messageList.size(); i++) {
                    WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(messageList.get(i).get("recipientId").toString(), messageList.get(i).get("messageText").toString());
                    if (messageList.get(i).get("senderId").toString().equals(currentUserId)) {
                        chatAdapter.addMessage(message, ChatAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
                    } else {
                        chatAdapter.addMessage(message, ChatAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage() {
    messageBody = messageBodyField.getText().toString();
    if (messageBody.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "messageService: " + messageService);
    Log.i(TAG, "recipientId: " + recipientId);
    Log.i(TAG, "messageBody: " + messageBody);
    messageService.sendMessage(recipientId, messageBody);
    messageBodyField.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    messageService.removeMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
        Log.i(TAG, "messageService::onServiceConnected: " + messageService);
        messageService.addMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        messageService = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "messageService::onServiceDisconnected: " + messageService);
    }
}

private class MyMessageClientListener implements MessageClientListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient client, Message message, MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Failed to send message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, final Message message) {
        if (message.getSenderId().equals(recipientId)) {
            final WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
            query.whereEqualTo("sinchId", message.getMessageId());
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if (messageList.size() == 0) {
                            ParseObject parseMessage = new ParseObject("ParseMessage");
                            parseMessage.put("senderId", currentUserId);
                            parseMessage.put("recipientId", writableMessage.getRecipientIds().get(0));
                            parseMessage.put("messageText", writableMessage.getTextBody());
                            parseMessage.put("sinchId", message.getMessageId());
                            parseMessage.saveInBackground();
                            chatAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, chatAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message, String recipientId) {
        final WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
        chatAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, ChatAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient client, MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient client, Message message, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {

    }
}
}
```

And the MessageService class code:

package com.example.aes.ctf;

```
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {
private static final String APP_KEY = "app-key";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "secret";
private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "";
private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
private MessageClient messageClient = null;
private String currentUserId;
//private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.example.aes.ctf.ListUsersActivity");
//private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
        startSinchClient(currentUserId);
    }
    //broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void startSinchClient(String username) {
    sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username)
            .applicationKey(APP_KEY).applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
            .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();
    sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);
    sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
    sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
    sinchClient.checkManifest();
    sinchClient.start();
}

private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
    return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
    /*broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);*/
    client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
    messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
}

@Override
public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
    client = null;
}

@Override
public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError sinchError) {
    /*broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", false);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);*/
    client = null;
}

@Override
public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient sinchClient, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {

}

@Override
public void onLogMessage(int i, String s, String s1) {

}

public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
    if (messageClient != null) {
        WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        messageClient.send(message);
    }
}

public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
    if (messageClient != null) {
        messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
    }
}

public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
    if (messageClient != null) {
        messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
    sinchClient.terminate();
}

public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {
    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
    }

    public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
        return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
    }
}
}
```

I can post more related code if needed. I've been stuck on this error for awhile.

EDIT:
I was able to fix it by changing

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return serviceInterface;
}
```

Thanks guy!

Comment: Post the stack trace showing the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}
```

You should implement a binder for your service and return it in the onBind method of your service, so in your MessageServiceInterface class declare following method:

```
    public MessageService getService() {
        Log.v("Serivce Bind", "Bind");
        return MessageService.this;
    }
}
```

And declare a field in `MessageService` class:

```
  IBinder binder = new MessageSeviceInterface();
```

Return binder instance in `onBind` method and finally get the allocated instance of `MessageService` using following code:

Replace

```
messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
```

With:

```
MessageService.MessageServiceInterface binder = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
messageService = binder.getService()`
```

Comment: How would I implement a binder for the service?

Comment: You have already implemented that, see the class MessageServiceInterface which is extended from Binder, just add the getService method to this class, and return the instance of  MessageServiceInerface class in onBind method!

Answer (score 0):

well, this is because you never **INITIALIZE** the **messageService** object.

it seems like you wish to start a service and then - control it from your activity... are you sure you wish to send messages from a service rather from an AsyncTask?

**AsyncTask** also run in the background and much more easier to control for this purpose...

try to chek this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Yes I know about AsyncTasks but I am not sure what exactly you mean. Why wouldn't I want to use a Service?

Comment: it seems like you want to execute your code ONCE from an  activity.. this is ideal for **AsyncTask**.  a service is a component that should also run in the background but for a large amount of time (execution an action after X seconds, or every X seconds, etc...)